# Disable Tensorflow debugging information

Tags: python, tensorflow

By debugging information I mean what TensorFlow shows in my terminal about loaded libraries and found devices etc. not Python errors.

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:900] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Graphics Device
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0885
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 12.00GiB
Free memory: 11.83GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:717] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Graphics Device, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:51] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.0KiB
...
```

Comment: tracking issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258

Comment: Tensorflow is still early alpha code and they're still working out the bugs for basic compatibility with numpy and pandas.  So to knock out these warnings in a single blow, do `import warnings` then `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`, then run your tensorflow imports and and code that relies on the broken alpha-tensorflow code, then turn warnings back on via `warnings.resetwarnings()`.  Tensorflow shouldn't be advertising a version name over 0.05 at this point in time.

Comment: I have the same problem, but then with the C++ API of Tensorflow (Lite). Setting environment variables before loading TF does not help. Also no help from the official TF (Lite) forum: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58050 Sigh, it's Oct 2022 and this problem still persists. Anybody who knows a solution for C++?

Answer (score 432):

You can disable all debugging logs using `os.environ` :

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf
```

Tested on tf 0.12 and 1.0

In details,

```
0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
1 = INFO messages are not printed
2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed
```

Comment: This works, but it removes the timestamp in front of the logs -- how can this be turned on again?

Comment: What are these levels (0, 1, 2, 3) mean?

Comment: not working for 1.13 and python3, even before import tensorflow

Comment: the only solution worked for me on TF2.0.0  It works only when put BEFORE importing tensorflow

Comment: Works on TF2.0 and Python 3. Import os before importing tensorflow.

Comment: not working for tf 2.4.1 and python 3.7 even before adding it to import tensorflow

Comment: This does not get everything.  Is there a way to even stop all tensorflow output, even plugin messages, like "Metal device set to: Apple M1"?

Comment: Works for TensorFlow 2.10, Python 3.9. Great help!

Answer (score 247):

**2.0 Update (10/8/19)**
Setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` should still work (see below in v0.12+ update), but there was a [reported issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31870) for version 2.0 until 2.3.z fixed in 2.4 and later. If setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` does not work for you (again, see below), try doing the following to set the log level:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('INFO')
```

In addition, please see the documentation on [`tf.autograph.set_verbosity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity) which sets the verbosity of autograph log messages - for example:

```py
# Can also be set using the AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY environment variable
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(1)
```

**v0.12+ Update (5/20/17), Working through TF 2.0+:**

In TensorFlow 0.12+, per this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258), you can now control logging via the environmental variable called `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`; it defaults to 0 (all logs shown) but can be set to one of the following values under the `Level` column.

```
  Level | Level for Humans | Level Description                  
 -------|------------------|------------------------------------ 
  0     | INFO             | [Default] Print all messages       
  1     | WARNING          | Filter out INFO messages           
  2     | ERROR            | Filter out INFO & WARNING messages 
  3     | NONE             | Filter out all messages
```

See the following generic OS example using Python:

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
```

You can set this environmental variable in the environment that you run your script in. For example, with bash this can be in the file `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, or in the actual shell as:

```bash
TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2 python my_tf_script.py
```

To be thorough, you call also set the level for the Python [`tf_logging`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging) module, which is used in e.g. summary ops, tensorboard, various estimators, etc.

```py
# append to lines above
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}
```

For 1.14 you will receive warnings if you do not change to use the v1 API as follows:

```py
# append to lines above
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}
```

---

**For Prior Versions of TensorFlow or TF-Learn Logging (v0.11.x or lower):**

View the page below for information on TensorFlow logging; with the new update, you're able to set the logging verbosity to either `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, or `FATAL`. For example:

```py
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

The page additionally goes over monitors which can be used with TF-Learn models. [Here is the page](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors).

This **doesn't** block all logging, though (only TF-Learn). I have two solutions; one is a 'technically correct' solution (Linux) and the other involves rebuilding TensorFlow.

```bash
script -c 'python [FILENAME].py' | grep -v 'I tensorflow/'
```

For the other, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331419/tensorflow-how-to-measure-how-much-gpu-memory-each-tensor-takes/36505898#36505898) which involves modifying source and rebuilding TensorFlow.

Comment: the "I tensorflow" messages can be annoying, tf should  provide some way of silencing them using api instead of rebuilding

Comment: This can also be done from command line: `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL="3" && python your_code.py`

Comment: It can also be run as `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL="3" python your_code.py`

Comment: Is there a way to turn tensorflow warnings/errors into errors?

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. AFAIK there is not (trivial) way of doing such, may I ask what you would like to accomplish by doing such @CMCDragonkai?

Comment: Using `tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0`. Recieved this output when called the function above

`The name tf.logging.set_verbosity is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity instead.`

`WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/.../NN.py:297: The name tf.logging.ERROR is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR instead.`

Pleasing that there were no no warnings after these messages

Comment: tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}  worked for me

Comment: only TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL worked for tensorflow-2.4.1

Comment: TF 2.9.1, `tf.logging` does not exist, `tf.get_logger().setLevel(...)` does not work. Only the method with the `os` environ var worked.

Comment: `tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')` worked for me.

Comment: The table of messages is misleading. `0` should be labeled `INFO` since it displays all messages. (Apparently there are no `DEBUG` messages?). Likewise, `1` should be `WARNING` since it displays `WARNING` and `ERROR` messages but not `INFO` messages. Likewise, `3` should be `NONE` since it filters out all messages.

Answer (score 61):

For **compatibility with Tensorflow 2.0**, you can use [`tf.get_logger`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/get_logger)

```
import logging
tf.get_logger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Worked for me with tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: Worked for me with 1.13.1. [Sample code](https://gist.github.com/oaakx/75de2b113067cd2cc6ab39ec38650a8f).

Comment: Also works as string with `tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for my error regarding 0 gradients

Comment: Nothing else but this worked for me in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 22):

I have had this problem as well (on `tensorflow-0.10.0rc0`), but could not fix the excessive nose tests logging problem via the suggested answers.

I managed to solve this by probing directly into the tensorflow logger. Not the most correct of fixes, but works great and only pollutes the test files which directly or indirectly import tensorflow:

```
# Place this before directly or indirectly importing tensorflow
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Worked for me, while TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL solution didn't. Good thinking!

Comment: Only solution that worked for me with tensorflow 1.12.

Comment: Using `tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0`. Recieved this output when called the function above

`The name tf.logging.set_verbosity is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity instead.`

`WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/.../NN.py:297: The name tf.logging.ERROR is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR instead.`

Pleasing that there were no no warnings after these messages

Answer (score 22):

I am using Tensorflow version 2.3.1 and none of the solutions above have been fully effective.
Until, I find [this](https://pypi.org/project/silence-tensorflow/) package.

Install like this:

with Anaconda,

```
python -m pip install silence-tensorflow
```

with IDEs,

```
pip install silence-tensorflow
```

And add to the first line of code:

```
from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow
silence_tensorflow()
```

That's It!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in this entire thread. Thanks! (I'm using Tensorflow 2.9.1)

Comment: It's a sad thing a separate package `silence-tensorflow`is needed to suppress the tensorflow output.

Answer (score 16):

To anyone still struggling to get the `os.environ` solution to work as I was, check that this is placed **before** you import `tensorflow` in your script, just like mwweb's answer:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: Only thing that worked with tensorflow-2.4.1

Comment: It's the only thing that work for me. I'm using `tensorflow-2.12.*`.

Answer (score 13):

I solved with this post  [Cannot remove all warnings #27045](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27045#issuecomment-477385197) , and the solution was:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
```

Comment: not working for FutureWarnings during tf import, tf=1.13.1 py3

Comment: Only this works for me! My configuration: Keras '2.2.4' (which uses tf 1.15.0) and Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 11):

As `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` didn't work for me you can try:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.WARN)
```

Worked for me in tensorflow v1.6.0

Answer (score 6):

Usual python3 log manager works for me with tensorflow==1.11.0:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 3):

for tensorflow 2.1.0, following code works fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just run the `silence_tensorflow` function from `silence-tensorflow` package before importing tensorflow:

```py
"""Module providing tools to shut up tensorflow useless warnings, letting you focus on the actual problems."""
import os
import logging


def silence_tensorflow():
    """Silence every unnecessary warning from tensorflow."""
    logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"] = "noverbose"
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    # We wrap this inside a try-except block
    # because we do not want to be the one package
    # that crashes when TensorFlow is not installed
    # when we are the only package that requires it
    # in a given Jupyter Notebook, such as when the
    # package import is simply copy-pasted.
    try:
        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
        tf.autograph.set_verbosity(3)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of this package.

Comment: `tf.autograph.set_verbosity()` is meant to use 0 for no logging, not 3

Answer (score 2):

To add some flexibility here, you can achieve more fine-grained control over the level of logging by writing a function that filters out messages however you like:

```
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').addFilter(my_filter_func)
```

where `my_filter_func` accepts a `LogRecord` object as input [[`LogRecord` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects)] and
returns zero if you want the message thrown out; nonzero otherwise.

Here's an example filter that only keeps every nth info message (Python 3 due
to the use of `nonlocal` here):

```
def keep_every_nth_info(n):
    i = -1
    def filter_record(record):
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        return int(record.levelname != 'INFO' or i % n == 0)
    return filter_record

# Example usage for TensorFlow:
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').addFilter(keep_every_nth_info(5))
```

All of the above has assumed that TensorFlow has set up its logging state already. You can ensure this without side effects by calling `tf.logging.get_verbosity()` before adding a filter.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I'm using tf 2.0-beta and want to enable/disable the default logging.  The environment variable and methods in tf1.X don't seem to exist anymore.

I stepped around in PDB and found this to work:

```
# close the TF2 logger
tf2logger = tf.get_logger()
tf2logger.error('Close TF2 logger handlers')
tf2logger.root.removeHandler(tf2logger.root.handlers[0])
```

I then add my own logger API (in this case file-based)

```
logtf = logging.getLogger('DST')
logtf.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# file handler
logfile='/tmp/tf_s.log'
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
fh.setFormatter( logging.Formatter('fh %(asctime)s %(name)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d :%(message)s') )
logtf.addHandler(fh)
logtf.info('writing to %s', logfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Jupyter notebooks, you can use the `%env` magic command:

```py
%env TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: This was the best solution for me, with the goal of creating a simple demonstration notebook that should not be bloated with additional packages or code lines

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling from this for a while, tried almost all the solutions here but could not get rid of debugging info in `TF 1.14`, I have tried following multiple solutions:

```
import os
import logging
import sys

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # FATAL
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel(tf.compat.v1.logging.FATAL)
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(tf.compat.v1.logging.FATAL)

sys.stderr = stderr

import absl.logging
logging.root.removeHandler(absl.logging._absl_handler)
absl.logging._warn_preinit_stderr = False
```

The debugging info still showed up, what finally helped was restarting my pc (actually restarting the kernel should work). So if somebody has similar problem, try restart kernel after you set your environment vars, simple but might not come in mind.

Answer (score 1):

After testing various suggestions so that they could also silence the resulting executable built with **PyInstaller**, I came up with this setting:

```py
import logging
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

import tensorflow as tf
```

The line

```py
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

will silent the warning about **rebuilding TensorFlow**:

> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA.
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

The line

```py
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

will silent the warning about **AutoGraph**:

> WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph is not available in this environment: functions lack code information. This is typical of some environments like the interactive Python shell. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.

The key point is to place these two **before** importing Tensorflow—despite Pylint's warning!

*tensorflow 2.11.0*

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to **get rid of warning outputs on the screen**, you might want to **clear the console** screen right after importing the tensorflow by using this simple command (Its more effective than disabling all debugging logs in my experience):

In windows:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

In Linux or Mac:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: 1. No, isn't more effective. 2. Is a potential security risk. 3. You should never call system for such tasks. 4. There are far better ways to do this as explained in many answers here.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above could solve my problem in Jupyter Notebook, so I use the following snippet code bellow from [Cicoria](https://www.cicoria.com/tensorflow-suppressing-futurewarning-numpy-messages-in-jupyter-notebooks/), and issues solved.

```
import warnings  
with warnings.catch_warnings():  
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=FutureWarning)
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here work, but you have to use them every time you open a new session (e.g. with JupyterLab). To make the changes stick, you have to set the environment variable.

Linux:

```bash
export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL="3"
```

(Also add the above line to .bashrc to make the change permanent, not just for the session)

Windows:

```
setx TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL "3"
```

Both set the environment variables for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me perfectly, to turn off all the loggs

```
import logging, os

logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"

import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apple M1 or Above GPU, you need to install package silence_tensorflow.

Run following command to install

```
python -m pip install silence-tensorflow
```

then add following lines in your code

```
from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow
silence_tensorflow()
```