# How to suppress verbose Tensorflow logging?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nose

I'm unittesting my Tensorflow code with nosetests but it produces such amount of verbose output that makes it useless.

The following test

```py
import unittest
import tensorflow as tf

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creation(self):
        self.assertEquals(True, False)
```

when run with `nosetests` creates a huge amount of useless logging:

```
FAIL: test_creation (tests.test_tf.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cebrian/GIT/thesis-nilm/code/deepmodels/tests/test_tf.py", line 10, in test_creation
    self.assertEquals(True, False)
AssertionError: True != False
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Const (<function _ConstantShape at 0x7f4379131c80>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Assert (<function no_outputs at 0x7f43791319b0>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Print (<function _PrintGrad at 0x7f4378effd70>) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Print (<function unchanged_shape at 0x7f4379131320>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering HistogramAccumulatorSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering HistogramSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering ImageSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering AudioSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering MergeSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering ScalarSummary (None) in gradient.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering ScalarSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering MergeSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering AudioSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering ImageSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering HistogramSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering HistogramAccumulatorSummary (<function _ScalarShape at 0x7f4378f042a8>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Pack (<function _PackShape at 0x7f4378f047d0>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Unpack (<function _UnpackShape at 0x7f4378f048c0>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering Concat (<function _ConcatShape at 0x7f4378f04938>) in shape functions.
tensorflow: Level 1: Registering ConcatOffset (<function _ConcatOffsetShape at 0x7f4378f049b0>) in shape functions.

......
```

whereas using tensorflow from the ipython console doesn't seem that verbose:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally

In [2]:
```

How could I suppress the former logging when running nosetests?

Comment: Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337601/nosetests-with-tensorflow-lots-of-debugging-output-how-to-disable

Answer (score 54):

**2.0 Update (10/8/19)**
Setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` should still work (see below in v0.12+ update), but there is currently an issue open (see [issue #31870](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31870)). If setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` does not work for you (again, see below), try doing the following to set the log level:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('INFO')
```

In addition, please see the documentation on [`tf.autograph.set_verbosity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity) which sets the verbosity of autograph log messages - for example:

```py
# Can also be set using the AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY environment variable
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(1)
```

**v0.12+ Update (5/20/17), Working through TF 2.0+:**

In TensorFlow 0.12+, per this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258), you can now control logging via the environmental variable called `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`; it defaults to 0 (all logs shown) but can be set to one of the following values under the `Level` column.

```
  Level | Level for Humans | Level Description                  
 -------|------------------|------------------------------------ 
  0     | DEBUG            | [Default] Print all messages       
  1     | INFO             | Filter out INFO messages           
  2     | WARNING          | Filter out INFO & WARNING messages 
  3     | ERROR            | Filter out all messages
```

See the following generic OS example using Python:

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
```

To be thorough, you call also set the level for the Python [`tf_logging`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging) module, which is used in e.g. summary ops, tensorboard, various estimators, etc.

```py
# append to lines above
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}
```

For 1.14 you will receive warnings if you do not change to use the v1 API as follows:

```py
# append to lines above
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}
```

---

**For Prior Versions of TensorFlow or TF-Learn Logging (v0.11.x or lower):**

View the page below for information on TensorFlow logging; with the new update, you're able to set the logging verbosity to either `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, or `FATAL`. For example:

```py
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

The page additionally goes over monitors which can be used with TF-Learn models. [Here is the page](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors).

This **doesn't** block all logging, though (only TF-Learn). I have two solutions; one is a 'technically correct' solution (Linux) and the other involves rebuilding TensorFlow.

```sh
script -c 'python [FILENAME].py' | grep -v 'I tensorflow/'
```

For the other, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331419/tensorflow-how-to-measure-how-much-gpu-memory-each-tensor-takes/36505898#36505898) which involves modifying source and rebuilding TensorFlow.

Comment: On TF 2.0, for me it worked by:
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

Answer (score 11):

Running the tests with `nosetests --nologcapture` will disable the display of these logs.
More information about the logging for nosetests:
https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/logcapture.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/619/commits/48603b7faed85753ab905f177cbf4e0c8d1dcb64) of doing this. Unfortunately this requires modifying the source and rebuilding. Here's a [tracking bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/566#issuecomment-229135282) to make it easier