# DEPRECATION WARNING: How to remove tf.keras warning "calling VarianceScaling.__init__ with dtype is deprecated..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The following code generates the warning in tensorflow r1.12 python API:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tensorflow as tf

M = tf.keras.models.Sequential();
M.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2));
```

The complete warning text is this:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0213 15:50:07.239809 140701996246848 deprecation.py:506] From /home/matias/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py:1253: calling VarianceScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
```

I have tried different approaches like initializing and calling a kernel initializer before adding Dense layer and passing it to Dense constructor, but it seems to not change anything. Is this warning inevitable? A 'yes' as an answer would be enough for me.

Comment: On tensorflow 1.12 I receive no such errors. Also, your formatting is all messed up (you have semi-colons at the end?)

Comment: It is not an error, but a warning. And yes, I use semi-colons at the end. Maybe it is important to mention that I installed tensorflow from source.

Comment: I installed tensorflow 1.12 from source too, and I  receive no such warnings too.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337601/nosetests-with-tensorflow-lots-of-debugging-output-how-to-disable if you want to suppress the warning

Answer (score 4):

The warning may be caused upstream by `abseil-py`, a dependency of `tensorflow`.
See the details [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26691).
An easy fix may be to update `abseil-py` by running:

`pip install --upgrade absl-py`

(In my case, the conflicting version was `0.7.1` and the problem was fixed in the updated version, `0.8.1`)

Answer (score 3):

You are running tensor flow 2.0 and it looks like VarianceScaling.**init** is deprecated. It might mean  that Sequential will need to be more explicitly initialized in the future. 
for example:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(32,)),
# Add another:
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning based on the [changes in Tensorflow 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2).

If you don't want to see these warnings, upgrade to TensorFlow 2.0. You can install the beta version via pip:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```