# Tensorflow logging messages do not appear

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, error-logging, python-logging

I use `tensorflow 1.2.0` installed with `pip install`.

When I run samples that include

```
import logging
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

the logging messages of the form

```
logging.info('TEST')
```

do not appear in the terminal output, even with the flag `--tostderr`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873777/1435500) I also tried

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
```

but still the problem persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26):

#### TF Logging Basics:

So there is a lot of confusion around tensorflow logging, and it is really not well documented. I landed here a few times in my searches, so it seems to be a good place to post an answer.

After some research and experimentation with Ubuntu and Windows (more than I had planned), this is what I got:

There are two flags, similarly named, but with somewhat different semantics:

- `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` - which has 3 or 4 basic levels - **low numbers = more messages**.

  - `0` outputs Information, Warning, Error, and Fatals (**default**)
  - `1` outputs Warning, and above
  - `2` outputs Errors and above.
  - etc... I didn't check edge cases
- `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` - which causes very very many extra *Information* errors - really for debugging only - **low numbers = less messages**.

  - `3` Outputs lots and lots of stuff
  - `2` Outputs less
  - `1` Outputs even less
  - `0` Outputs nothing extra (**default**)

#### Additional Notes:

- Since all the VLOG messages are Informational, then LOG needs to be set at 0 for you to see them. Fortunately that is the default.
- These errors go to the standard error so you can redirect them with something like:

  - `python tf-program.py &>mylog.log`
- These are supposed to be picked up by the `os` module so you should be able to set them in the environment
- Without the VLOG and with no GPU there are not that many information messages, so you can think logging is not working when it really is.

#### Windows:

- Except python's `os` module did not pick them up under Windows. Python never loved Windows...

  - this code sequence works for me in Windows (and would surely work in Linux):

    - `import os`
    - `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'`
    - `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = '3'`
    - `import tensorflow as tf`

#### Linux:

- Under Linux (bash) you can specify these conveniently on the command line, so with something like:

  - `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=3 python tf-program.py`

FWIW, I tested on TensorFlow 1.7 with this tutorial:

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/mnist
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are really two logging systems in tensorflow: one in the C++ core (specifically tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.{h,cc}) and the other in the Python bindings. **The two systems are independent.**

The one in the Python binding plays nicely with the standard Python logging module. The C++ logger is indepedently controlled by the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` environment variables mentioned in previous answers.

The following Python (that I locally called logtest.py) demonstrates the two systems' independence.

```
"""
Demonstrate independence of TensorFlow's two logging subsystems.
"""

import argparse
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger( "tensorflow" )

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description="Demo TensorFlow logging" )

parser.add_argument("-v","--verbosity",
    default="",
    choices=['DEBUG','INFO','WARNING','ERROR','CRITICAL'],
    help="One of {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}" )

args = parser.parse_args()

print( "Initial Python effective log level:", _logger.getEffectiveLevel() )

# If user provided an explicit Python level, set it.

if args.verbosity:
    _logger.setLevel( args.verbosity   )
    print( " ...new Python effective log level:", _logger.getEffectiveLevel() ) # ...and confirm the change.

_logger.debug(    "   DEBUG messages are emitted" )
_logger.info(     "    INFO messages are emitted" )
_logger.warn(     " WARNING messages are emitted" )
_logger.error(    "   ERROR messages are emitted" )
_logger.critical( "CRITICAL messages are emitted" )

with tf.Session() as s:
    pass # ...just to trigger TensorFlow into action to generate logging.
```

Running...

`TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 python3 logtest.py -v CRITICAL`

...shows that Python can't silence the core logging system, and

`TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=5 python3 logtest.py -v DEBUG`

...shows that the core system can't silence Python.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do to control the TensorFlow logging is to have this piece of code **before** any TensorFlow import

```
import os
import logging
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

import tensorflow as tf
```

I'd be happy to hear about any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL but still not work.
after check this thread
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258

as it said

> It's TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL, not TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL
>   Also, note that if TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL is set, then TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL
>   values are ignored

then I unset TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL  and set TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL again,
it works.

the two macro makes me confused
hope it helps.