# Tensorflow 2.4.0 not detecting GPU despite using compatible versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I recently moved to tensorflow 2 from tensorflow 1.x -gpu. But TF is not recognizing the GPU anymore.
I use Spyder with a NON-ANACONDA interpreter. I use pip to manage my packages. OS is Windows 10. The GPU is a GTX 1660 Ti, so it does support CUDA.

- Py version -- Python 3.7
- Current TF version -- 2.4.0
- Current CUDA version -- 11.1
- Current CUDNN version -- 8.0.4.30

-I have copied all the CUDNN dlls after extraction as specified here -- https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html

-All the necessary path variables have been added as well. I have Visual Studio 2019 as well as Visual Code installed from before (when
I used to run tensorflow on my GPU)

```
NVIDIA SMI output :-
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvidia-smi
Tue Feb  9 17:08:11 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.40       Driver Version: 461.40       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   76C    P0    26W /  N/A |    273MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     15272    C+G   ...n64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16500      C   ...iles\Python37\pythonw.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


nvcc --version :-
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:54:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.relgpu_drvr455TC455_06.29190527_0

tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
Out[9]: False
```

As per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source I have the correct combination of CUDNN and CUDA installed. Yet, tf doesn't recognize my gpu.
Thanks in advance for your time :)

Edit 1 -- Added the log received after importing tensorflow in cmd
Edit 2 -- Added log level as specified in [Tensorflow logging messages do not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853059/tensorflow-logging-messages-do-not-appear/49756653)

```
>>> os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL']='3'
>>> os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='0'
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-02-09 18:10:16.489113:Itensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
    2021-02-09 18:10:16.558283: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/gcs_file_system.cc:804] GCS cache max size = 0 ; block size = 67108864 ; max staleness = 0
    2021-02-09 18:10:16.562188: I .\tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/ram_file_block_cache.h:64] GCS file block cache is disabled
    2021-02-09 18:10:16.565031: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/gcs_file_system.cc:844] GCS DNS cache is disabled, because GCS_RESOLVE_REFRESH_SECS = 0 (or is not set)
    2021-02-09 18:10:16.568337: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/gcs_file_system.cc:874] GCS additional header DISABLED. No environment variable set.
```

Edit 2 -- Adding evidence where PyTorch registers the GPU as mentioned in [How to check if pytorch is using the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152674/how-to-check-if-pytorch-is-using-the-gpu)

```
import torch

torch.cuda.current_device()
Out[2]: 0

torch.cuda.device(0)
Out[3]: <torch.cuda.device at 0x222be69a8c8>

torch.cuda.device_count()
Out[4]: 1

torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
Out[5]: 'GeForce GTX 1660 Ti'

torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: When you import tensorflow, a log is printed on the terminal, please include in your question.

Comment: Added it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: That is not the whole log, it should mention all the cuda libs

Comment: I've tried increasing the log level, this is all I get

Comment: Try training a basic model and show the full log because importing tensorflow is not sufficient to tell what's wrong unless it's a known problem with a known solution.

Comment: Yes that is true, train a model and the full log should be output.

Comment: Add CUDA, CUPTI, cuDNN directories to %PATH% variable. Verify your installation against given instructions in [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) site.Thanks!