# how to make Tensorflow 2.8.0 Logging work?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, logging

I want to print debugging or logging messages in the Python (high level operations) and C++ (inner operations and kernel implementation) of tensorflow 2.8.0, however neither seems to work.

I tried two builds of tensorflow: the latest version (2.8.0) and the master branch version (2.9)

For Python API logging, I used `tf.get_logger().setLevel("DEBUG")`

For C++ logging, as mentioned in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853059/tensorflow-logging-messages-do-not-appear) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073432/how-to-suppress-verbose-tensorflow-logging/38873777#38873777), I tried using `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=2` in two ways:

(1) independently of the code as environment variables:
`TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=2; python tf_test.py`

(2) Or inside the code using the os module (`os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=2']`). Tried putting this call before and after importing tensorflow as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31870).

However, nothing seems to work.

Here is the example I'm using:

```
import os 

#os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = "2"

import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = "2"

a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(2)), name="a")

print(a)
```

Does anyone have a clue how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

After some digging, I worked it out:

`TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` has been renamed to `TF_CPP_MAX_VLOG_LEVEL`. It works only when setting the variable before importing tensorflow.

`TF_CPP_MAX_VLOG_LEVEL` produces a lot of output regarding the internal C++ operations.

`TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` controls warnings, info, error messages.