# How to disable too verbose Tensorflow 2.4 logging?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I just can't get Tensorflow 2.4 to use less verbose logging messages.
Basically, I wished to display less info (I) logging messages, or warnings (W) only.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
# (module imports...)
import tensorflow as tf
import os


# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073432/how-to-suppress-verbose-tensorflow-logging
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity
os.environ["AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY"] = "0"

tf.get_logger().setLevel("WARNING")

# (every other code for the model)
```

**My environment:**

```
- NVIDIA Docker container nvidia/cuda:11.2.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04 where training is happening
- Tensorflow 2.4.0
- Python 3.8
```

**Actual results:**

```
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218556: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218746: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218777: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-04-29 00:34:22.218841: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-04-29 00:34:22.222104: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-04-29 00:34:22.222182: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-04-29 00:34:22.906654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-04-29 00:34:22.906697: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-04-29 00:34:22.906707: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
```

**Expected results:**

Anything less verbose.
Any setting resulting in less logging messages.
Ideal solution: only warning level logging messages.

Comment: You need to do this *before* you import Tensorflow

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks a ton!! I did not think of this and probably could have searched for another couple of hours for a solution...