# Force TensorFlow to use Python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, logging, tensorflow2.0

I am developping a Python app that uses TensorFlow as well as Python's standard [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library.

Upon starting my application, I initialize `logging` with my own formats and handlers. However, no matter what I do, I can't get to apply it to Tensorflow logging.

When I start a Tensorflow operation for the first time, I get lines like these output to the console (not sure if they're on stdout or stderr):

```
2021-11-02 14:16:05.249391: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2021-11-02 14:16:05.249576: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

They don't match the format I set for my log lines and they don't get written to the log file when I use a `FileHandler`.

*Question*: How can I get these log events to be handled by Python's logging system, or in the worst case to be removed entirely?

I am using the TensorFlow package present on PyPI and I would like to avoid re-building it at all costs.

Also I don't care about solving the warning reported by the log lines (my computer doesn't even have an Nvidia GPU), what I want is to get **all** TensorFlow log lines themselves either gone or handled by Python logging.

**EDIT** As an attempt to solve this issue, I already have following code as part of my logging intialization:

```py
    tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0)
    tflogger = tf.get_logger()
    tflogger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    for handler in tflogger.handlers[:]:
        tflogger.removeHandler(handler)
    tflogger.propagate = True
```

EDIT #2: I would like to avoid touching to environment variables in order to avoid having to set them up everytime I'm using the application (poissibly on different machines)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873777/51685 help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have already tried resetting `tf.get_logger()` (edit incoming) and I'd like to avoid depending on environment variables (to make it easier to set up). As for `tf.logging`, it does not exists in TF 2.6.

Comment: Hold on, I didn't see the part about `tf.autograph`. Testing now.

Comment: Tested, and it has no effect on these log items...

Comment: Hi @Nathan.EilishaShiraini, did you ever find a solution for this ? I'm in the same situation