# Refactoring Tensorflow FLAGS

Tags: python, tensorflow

After using many python scripts with the same Tensorflow FLAGS, I got tired of updating multiple flags for each change and so decided to refactor `tf.app.flags` into a separate class which I could reuse across scripts.

However, for some strange reason, whenever I use `self.flags` in a different method it fails to recognise a previously set flag. The following class for example will work fine for flag `project_dir2` but will fail for flag `project_dir3`

```
`class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
     self.flags = tf.app.flags
     self.FLAGS = self.flags.FLAGS

     #test code that works here
     self.flags.DEFINE_string("project_dir2", "aValue", "project directory")
     print("This will print correctly: "+self.FLAGS.project_dir2)
     self.my_function()

  def my_function(self):
     #test code that fails
     self.flags.DEFINE_string("project_dir3", "aValue", "project directory")
     print("This will fail: "+self.FLAGS.project_dir3)`
```

I get the following exception:

`AttributeError: project_dir2
Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",) in <function _remove at 0x7fd4c3090668> ignored`

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? Or is this something you simply cannot do with Tensorflow flags? Does that mean there's no way of refactoring commonly used flag settings across scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an internal method called `_parse_flags()` which is called [on first access](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/297ca67a8a06bb7128476761cfee8d56145ee49a/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py#L40). You could call it manually after you update it

IE

```
  def my_function(self):
    #test code that fails
    self.flags.DEFINE_string("project_dir3", "aValue", "project directory")
    self.flags.FLAGS._parse_flags()
```

Background on tf.flags - it's a partial re-implementation of Google's [gflags](https://github.com/google/python-gflags) library so it's missing features/documentation. It's a contributions to do something smarter like plug in official gflags ([issue 1258](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258)). That allow things like controlling verbose logging (which requires a recompile [right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331419/tensorflow-how-to-measure-how-much-gpu-memory-each-tensor-takes/36505898#36505898))

Comment: Thank you so much ! ! ! Works perfectly now. You're just after saving me quite a few hours of work :-) Cheers