# Is there a way to suppress the messages TensorFlow prints?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I think that those messages are really important for the first few times but then it is just useless.
It is actually making things worse to read and debug.

> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA
>   library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3459] Unable to load cuDNN
>   DSO I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully
>   opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcuda.so.1 locally I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA
>   library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

Is there a way to suppress the ones that just say it was successful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information

Answer (score 63):

**UPDATE** (beyond 1.14): see my more thorough answer here (this is a dupe question anyway): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38645250/6557588

In addition to Wintro's answer, you can also disable/suppress TensorFlow logs from the C side (i.e. the uglier ones starting with single characters: I, E, etc.); the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258) open regarding logging has been updated to state that you can now control logging via an environmental variable. You can now change the level by setting the environmental variable called `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`; it defaults to 0 (all logs shown), but can be set to 1 to filter out `INFO` logs, 2 to additionally filter out `WARNING` logs, and 3 to additionally filter out `ERROR` logs. It appears to be in master now, and will likely be a part of future version (i.e. versions after r0.11). See [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258) for more information. Here is an example of changing the verbosity using Python:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
```

You can set this environmental variable in the environment that you run your script in. For example, with bash this can be in the file `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, or in the actual shell as:

```sh
TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2 python my_tf_script.py
```

Answer (score 38):

You can set the verbosity levels of TensorFlow's logging using

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

where `ERROR` can be any of `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, or `FATAL`. See [the logging module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging/set_verbosity).

However, setting this to `ERROR` does not always completely block all `INFO` logs, to completely block them you have two main choices in my opinion.

- If you are using Linux, you can just `grep` out all output strings beginning with `I tensorflow/`.
- Otherwise, you can completely rebuild TensorFlow with some modified files. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36505898/5695018).

If you're using TensorFlow version 1 (1.X), you can use

```
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: In tensorflow 2.0 I'm getting `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'`

Comment: @ProQ Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information/38645250#38645250) - in short use `tf.get_logger()` instead, or `tf.compat.v1.logging` (not recommended), as well as the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` variable

Answer (score 32):

As of **Tensorflow v1.14** (yes, including version **2.x**) you can use the native logging module to silence Tensorflow:

```py
import logging
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # FATAL
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.FATAL)
```

---

I personally use this in my projects:

```py
def set_tf_loglevel(level):
    if level >= logging.FATAL:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    if level >= logging.ERROR:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    if level >= logging.WARNING:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
    else:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
    logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(level)
```

so that I can disable tf logging by running:

```py
set_tf_loglevel(logging.FATAL)
```

and I can re-enable with

```py
set_tf_loglevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 19):

I created a function which shuts TF up. I call it on start of my programs. Some messages are very annoying and I cannot do anything about them...

```
def tensorflow_shutup():
    """
    Make Tensorflow less verbose
    """
    try:
        # noinspection PyPackageRequirements
        import os
        from tensorflow import logging
        logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

        # Monkey patching deprecation utils to shut it up! Maybe good idea to disable this once after upgrade
        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        def deprecated(date, instructions, warn_once=True):
            def deprecated_wrapper(func):
                return func
            return deprecated_wrapper

        from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
        deprecation.deprecated = deprecated

    except ImportError:
        pass
```

**Edit**: This is for TF 2.0 and up:

```py
def tensorflow_shutup():
    """
    Make Tensorflow less verbose
    """
    try:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

        # noinspection PyPackageRequirements
        import tensorflow as tf
        from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation

        tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

        # Monkey patching deprecation utils to shut it up! Maybe good idea to disable this once after upgrade
        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        def deprecated(date, instructions, warn_once=True):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
            def deprecated_wrapper(func):
                return func
            return deprecated_wrapper

        deprecation.deprecated = deprecated

    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Comment: formidable determination

Comment: Cool but does not work.. still same message:

2021-04-29 21:54:07.369239: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

Comment: @JiriOtoupalイりオトウパー It works for me. I've updated it for TF 2.x. You just need to call this function before importing tensorflow!

Answer (score 14):

To anyone still struggling to get the `os.environ` solution to work as I was, check that this is placed **before** you import `tensorflow` in your script, just like craymichael's answer:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/silence_tensorflow) is what worked for me:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"] = "noverbose"
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering previous answers, in Tensorflow 1.14 is actually possible to eliminate all the message generated by the library by including in the code the following two lines:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

This method exploits both the environment variable approach and Tensorflow logging module.

**Note:** the compatibility version is necessary to avoids further warnings given by the library, since the standard one is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

For tensorflow 2.2 you can disable the logging with the following lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf   
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without introducing any packages other than TensorFlow itself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0) # "0" means no logging.
```

For more details, check this TensorFlow API [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity).

Comment: Thanks, I was getting unimportant XLA warnings with 2.2.0 on W10 about being unable to invoke ptxas and this was the necessary solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to just see the output upon import and suppress the rest, you could make a context manager like this

```py
import os
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def suppress_tf_after_import():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
        
        
with suppress_tf_after_import():
    import tensorflow as tf
```