# How to Suppress Tensorflow warning displayed in result

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I have a python code connected with Tensorflow. It is supposed to return single result set. But i'm getting below mentioned warning along with result.

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   C:\Users\vsureshx079451\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\objectives.py:66:
>   calling reduce_sum (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with
>   keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating: keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims
>   instead 2018-02-04 19:12:04.860370: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX AVX2
>
> ### Result Here!

I will just put a small snippet of TensorFlow code here. Please let me know how to suppress this warning.

Note: I'm calling this Python file from C#. So i dont want to display anything other than result.

Code Snippet:

```
self.words = data['words']
        self.classes = data['classes']
        train_x = data['train_x']
        train_y = data['train_y']
        with open('intents.json') as json_data:
            self.intents = json.load(json_data)
        #input("Press Enter to continue...")
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
        net = tflearn.regression(net)
        # Define model and setup tensorboard
        self.model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
```

Edit:
I tried this as well, it didn't work.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Answer (score 76):

After searching hours together i found answer from Stackoverflow itself, where the answer is provided for different issue. And that solution worked here as well.

Here is the solution for TF 1.x:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

For TF 2.x:

```
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Source:
[Is there a way to suppress the messages TensorFlow prints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426502/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-the-messages-tensorflow-prints)

Comment: but what to do in case I'm using keras and not tensorflow directly

Comment: worked for me, both with keras and tf.keras models

Comment: The name `tf.logging.set_verbosity` is deprecated. Please use `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity` instead. The name `tf.logging.ERROR` is deprecated. Please use `tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR` instead.

Comment: I got best result with combination of the two methods.