# When I install my tensorflow 1.15 then I am facing such warning continuously

Tags: python, tensorflow

WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
- https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
- https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
  If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py:1612: Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.

Comment: Those are just deprecation warnings, they simply mean what they say no more, they are helpful for writing maintainable code, you may be able to suppress them like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608776/how-to-suppress-tensorflow-warning-displayed-in-result) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u).

Answer (score 0):

Those are the deprecation warnings as commented by @aim97.

You can turn off the warnings by using

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```