# turn off tensorflow messages

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I turn off tensorflow messages such as :

```
2019-08-14 16:07:26.928502: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:54] Adam_3/decay/initial_value: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0

2019-08-14 16:07:26.928520: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:54] noisy_layer_4_target: (Placeholder)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
....
```

I've tried :

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR) # also tried  DEBUG, FATAL, WARN, INFO
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
```

from other SO questions but they don't change anything.

I'm using keras with tf as backend , with tf.version = 1.14, in spyder

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426709/10400883).

> Setting `tf.logging.set_verbosity` to ERROR does not always completely block all INFO logs.

In Linux, you can try below.

> If you are using Linux, you can just grep out all output strings beginning with `I tensorflow/`

Example:

```
$ python main.py | grep -v "unwanted_word"
```

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for the answer. Can I use grep from inside spyder to filter the output of my script? Googling doesn't give me an answer

Comment: I get: "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging' " any ideas ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## append to lines above [tf_logging](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging)

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)  # or any {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import logging, os 
logging.disable(logging.WARNING) 
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
```