# non-resource variables are not supported in the long term

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a chatbot with Jupyter notebook and when I run the script I get this error;

> > WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\compat\v2_compat.py:96:
> > disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope)
> > is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions
> > for updating: non-resource variables are not supported in the long
> > term

I don't know how to solve this issue. My code is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json


with open("D:\intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)



words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

    if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])

words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels)

training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []

    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)

    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)


training = numpy.array(training)
output = numpy.array(output)
```

Answer (score 4):

The warning usually comes when you use the older version of Tensrflow like 1.x or if you have migrated from `Tensrflow 1.x` to `Tensorflow 2.x` using automated script.

If you are using `Tensorflow 1.x`, you can consider upgrading to `Tensorflow 2.x` since it has lot of performance advantages compared to older version and will be stable for the long run.

In Tensorflow 2.x using tf.Variable creates a Resource variable as default with eager execution is enabled by default.

Coming to the warning `tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables()` is depreciated instead you can mention `use_resource= False` in `tf.get_variable()` which will be forced to true when eager excecution is enabled by default in `Tensorflow 2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

As "Tech with Tim" mentioned in his video [Python Chat Bot Tutorial - Chatbot with Deep Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wypVcNIH6D4), he said:

> Python 3.7 contains bug.

So just install Python 3.6 from the Official [Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/).

Answer (score 0):

I found answer under different issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426502/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-the-messages-tensorflow-prints)

Solution for TF 1.x:

> tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

For TF 2.x:

> tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

Ensure that this is placed before you import `tensorflow` in your script

Comment: for tf 2.x, if you place it before you import tf, how can you use tf.compat.[...] ?