# TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows: "OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits" with test code

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)) using:

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

When I try running the test script from https://web.archive.org/web/20170214034751/https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#test_the_tensorflow_installation in Eclipse 4.5 or in the console:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('TensorFlow version: {0}'.format(tf.__version__))
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I obtain some error message:

```
TensorFlow version: 1.0.0-rc2
'Hello, TensorFlow!'
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflob
w\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
```

Why?

I didn't have such issues with TensorFlow 0.12.1  (installed with `pip install tensorflow==0.12.1`):

```
TensorFlow version: 0.12.1
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Comment: Could you file an issue on our github issue [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) and CC drpngx@? This is more of an install issue on windows.

Comment: @drpng thanks: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Installing [today's nightly build](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/85/) (CPU version):

```
pip install --upgrade http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/85/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow-1.0.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

fixed the issue (no more  `“OpKernel ('op: ”BestSplits“ device_type: ”CPU“') for unknown op: BestSplits”` etc.).

There are now some SSE warnings:

```
TensorFlow version: 1.0.0-rc2
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
2017-02-15 19:56:22.688266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-15 19:56:22.688266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-15 19:56:22.689266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-15 19:56:22.689266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-15 19:56:22.689266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-15 19:56:22.689266: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

in which case you can try [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/395857)

---

[TensorFlow 1.0.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20170219153708/https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md) was released a few days ago. However, it has the same issue. A more recent nightly build has [different warnings](https://web.archive.org/web/20170219153938/https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500#issuecomment-280576326):

```
sess = tf.Session()
2017-02-17 13:01:59.790943: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

FYI:  [Tensorflow macOS binary, compiled with SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and AVX optimizations.](https://github.com/Thunderbottom/Tensorflow-macOS-binary)

---

To hide the warnings/errors, you can [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35911252/395857) `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'`, e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
print('TensorFlow version: {0}'.format(tf.__version__))
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

`TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`:

- `0`: all logs shown (that's the default setting)
- `1`: filter out `INFO` logs
- `2`: additionally filter out `WARNING` logs
- `3`: additionally filter out `ERROR` logs.

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening on my machine as well, exactly as described here.  I get a clean print result from `print(sess.run(x))`, but when creating a session `sess = tf.Session()` I get the same errors.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt I've installed tensorflow the gpu version on window10 and suffers the same problem. Would the above solution work in my case as well? My worry is that would it be okay to install the cpu version tf on the system on which I've installed the gpu version tf already?

Comment: @julypraise did you install TensorFlow-GPU nightly build?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No, I've installed the mere 'TensorFlow-GPU' provided by the official site. Namely, I installed this using 'pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu' as this command is provided by the official website. So are you suggesting me to install by 'http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=gpu,OS=windows/92/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl', which is, it seems, what you meant?

Comment: @julypraise yes, though keep in mind that these warnings/errors are harmless so in practice we can just ignore them.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you very much. Your question and answers contribute a lot to me.

Comment: Getting the same warning messages on both CPU and GPU builds. I know they're harmless, but they're also annoying. Is there any way to hide the warnings from the output?

Comment: @Jakob added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Refering to suggestions above, I think doing 2 steps is helpful:

1st, upgrade tensorflow:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.1.0rc1
```

then, error logs changes into warn logs:

```
W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

2nd, you may be able to suppress the warning filter at level 2.

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

I think it works well without filtering 'error' logs.

Comment: With the version another warning appear.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to suppress the warning filter at level 2. This worked for me with TensorFlow 1.0.1 in a virtualenv install.

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

Sry about the additional answer, but I'm not worthy of commenting.

Comment: I still get errors with level 2 in TensorFlow 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is fixed in the version 1.1.0rc0 and later.

Find the latest version of tensorflow:

```
pip search --version tensorflow
```

Upgrade tensorflow:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.1.0rc1
```