# tensorflow Error after successful installation in windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10

After successful installation of Python and TensorFlow, when I ran the given program to test my installation, I got the following errors

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Please [edit] your question to include the text of the error, in a code block (use the `{}` formatting button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows: "OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device\_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits" with test code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217532/tensorflow-version-1-0-0-rc2-on-windows-opkernel-op-bestsplits-device-typ)

Answer (score 0):

There are just warnings. Don't worry, you can ignore them unless you need to use some of these operators: BestSplits,CountExtremelyRandomStats,...