# new to tensorflow, test errors, fix is to upgrade nightly?

Tags: tensorflow

I recently installed python 3.5.3 and followed the instructions on: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows
to install tensorflow using pip3.
I ran the small test code to see if everything works and got this:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>>>
```

After a bit of research i found this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500 that says I have to upgrade to the latest nightly...but I don't really know what that means or how to do it exactly. Also they say this error is not a big deal but I still want to fix.

EDIT: I seem to have a new problem:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-02-19 14:29:49.027704: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.027831: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.027999: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.028141: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.028279: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.028421: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.028559: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-02-19 14:29:49.028700: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Do I have to recompile things and how?

Comment: Did you read  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500? It answers your two questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows: "OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device\_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits" with test code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217532/tensorflow-version-1-0-0-rc2-on-windows-opkernel-op-bestsplits-device-typ)

Comment: From my understanding of the links you suggested, this is still an ongoing problem as we wait for more stable builds to be released?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upgrade to the latest nightly build for CPU:

```
pip install --upgrade http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/lastBuild/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

You can go on http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/ for more wheels.