# Q: TensorFlow 1.0.1 OpKernel unknown op error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed the latest version of tensorflow into an Anaconda virtual environment. Running the Hello World test gives the OpKernel unknown op error. This is just like [TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows: "OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits" with test code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217532/tensorflow-version-1-0-0-rc2-on-windows-opkernel-op-bestsplits-device-typ) , but there the fix was to run the nightly build to avoid a problem in 1.0.0-rc2.

My build is #116 (Mar 18, 2017 2:25:00 AM) tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl, which should contain the above mentioned fix. It appears the only subsequent build (#1​17 Mar 19, 2017 2:25 AM) failed. I have pasted my session log below.

Bruce

```
c:\users\bruce>conda create --name TF python=3.5
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\Bruce\Anaconda2\envs\TF:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:            9.0.1-py35_1
    python:         3.5.3-0
    setuptools:     27.2.0-py35_1
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

python-3.5.3-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:08   3.83 MB/s

c:\users\bruce>activate TF

(TF) c:\users\bruce>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tensorflow==1.0.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (14.7MB)
    100% |################################| 14.7MB 92kB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (7.7MB)
    100% |################################| 7.7MB 174kB/s
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 4.6MB/s
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading protobuf-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (360kB)
    100% |################################| 368kB 2.2MB/s
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading setuptools-34.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (389kB)
    100% |################################| 399kB 2.1MB/s
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.1)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |################################| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy, wheel, six, appdirs, pyparsing, packaging, setuptools, protobuf, tensorflow
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 numpy-1.12.1 packaging-16.8 protobuf-3.2.0 pyparsing-2.2.0 setuptools-34.3.2 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.0.1 wheel-0.29.0

(TF) c:\users\bruce>python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>>> exit()

(TF) c:\users\bruce>
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been fixed in the [`master`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master) branch of TensorFlow, but the fix is not in the [`r1.0`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.0) release branch from which the 1.0 and 1.0.1 releases were made. It will be in the next release (1.1), but for now you have the choice of ignoring the error messages—which are fortunately harmless—compiling from source, or using a nightly build.