# Tensorflow error when running first time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I ran a simple tensorflow script to see if it was working. After I ran my code, I got the following errors:

```
 E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
```

I tried the solution posted here ([TensorFlow version 1.0.0-rc2 on Windows: "OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits" with test code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217532/tensorflow-version-1-0-0-rc2-on-windows-opkernel-op-bestsplits-device-typ)), but that link given did not work for me. Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in TensorFlow 1.1, which is now available as a release candidate. You can upgrade to that version using the command:

```
C:\> pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.1.0rc0
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I have another error now... I'll figure it out.