# How to hide tensorflow session logs from terminal, for a clean verbosity

Tags: tensorflow

When I run the tensorflow script, I should be able to observe only the expected verbosity in the terminal. Not the tensorflow
 Session start messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Tensorflow debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)

Comment: Definite duplicate of [Disable Tensorflow debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
```

Or

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```