# Tensorflow Allocation Memory: Allocation of 38535168 exceeds 10% of system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, keras-layer, resnet

Using ResNet50 pre-trained Weights I am trying to build a classifier. The code base is fully implemented in Keras high-level Tensorflow API. The complete code is posted in the below GitHub Link.

Source Code: [Classification Using RestNet50 Architecture](https://gist.github.com/Madhivarman/676650f71ec35a5f2802631fcfa0ff73)

The file size of the pre-trained model is **94.7mb**.

I loaded the pre-trained file

```
new_model = Sequential()

new_model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False,
                pooling='avg',
                weights=resnet_weight_paths))
```

and fit the model

```
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'path_to_the_training_set',
    target_size = (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size = 12,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
    )

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'path_to_the_validation_set',
    target_size = (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
    class_mode = 'categorical'
    )

#compile the model

new_model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = 3,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = 1
)
```

and in the Training dataset, I have two folders dog and cat, each holder almost 10,000 images. When  I compiled the script, I get the following error

> Epoch 1/1 2018-05-12 13:04:45.847298: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 38535168
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:46.845021: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:47.552176: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:48.199240: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:48.918930: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:49.274137: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 19267584
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:49.647061: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 19267584
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:50.028839: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 19267584
> exceeds 10% of system memory. 2018-05-12 13:04:50.413735: W
> tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 19267584
> exceeds 10% of system memory.

Any ideas to optimize the way to load the pre-trained model (or) get rid of this warning message?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, does the model run after these messages?

Comment: Yes it run.....

Comment: In that case, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121886/6824418 ? Unless there's some other reason you need to reduce the memory usage.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try reducing batch_size attribute to a small number(like 1,2 or 3).
Example:

```
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'path_to_the_training_set',
    target_size = (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size = 2,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
    )
```

Comment: How come reducing the batch_size fixes this? (Intuitively it'd mean the training/validation data takes up less memory but I don't see how!)

Comment: @Omrii It's a matter of caching. Most data loaders do not keep all of the data in memory at all times, and nearly all do not keep significant data in the GPU memory. By decreasing the batch_size, you decrease the amount of data needed at any step of the training, allowing for less to be loaded at a time and still maintain optimal throughput. So no, the data is not smaller, but yes, it does take up less RAM and video RAM. Tensorflow is being clever here to save you headache.

Comment: Keep in mind that batch size is a hyper parameter which affects the gradient decent trajectory and might push you into different optima - therefore using a larger machine (in the cloud) would help

Answer (score 23):

I was having the same problem while running Tensorflow container with Docker and Jupyter notebook. I was able to fix this problem by increasing the container memory.

On **Mac OS**, you can easily do this from:

```
       Docker Icon > Preferences >  Advanced > Memory
```

Drag the scrollbar to maximum (e.g. 4GB). Apply and it will restart the Docker engine.

Now run your tensor flow container again.

It was handy to use the `docker stats` command in a separate terminal
It shows the container memory usage in realtime, and you can see how much memory consumption is growing:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME   CPU %   MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %    NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
3170c0b402cc   mytf   0.04%   588.6MiB / 3.855GiB   14.91%   13.1MB / 3.06MB     214MB / 3.13MB      21
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2` to filter out info and warning messages. I found that on [this github issue where they complain about the same output](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18736). To do so within python, you can use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121886/786020):

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

You can even turn it on and off at will with this. I test for the maximum possible batch size before running my code, and I can disable warnings and errors while doing this.

Comment: With this the message is not show, but the problem persists

Comment: @VMMF In my case and the case of the original question, this was not a problem. It was only using over 10%, and I explicitly test for maximal utilization, so of course I'll exceed that. If you are running into a utilization problem that is actually a problem, then you're likely going to need to do more work. Decrease the batch size. Decrease the image size or network size, which is likely undoable in pretrained models such as in the question. If you are continuing to have issues, I recommend opening a question more in line with the problem you are having, and we will give it our best to help.

Answer (score 6):

I was running a small model on a CPU and had the same issue. Adding:`os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` resolved it.

Comment: With this the message is not show, but the problem persists

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, and i concluded that there are two factors to be considered when see this error:
1- batch_size ==> because this responsible for the data size to be processed for each epoch 
2- image_size ==> the higher image dimensions (image size), more data to be processed

So for these two factors, the RAM cannot handle all of required data.

To solve the problem I tried two cases: 
The first change batch_size form 32 to 3 or 2 
The second reduce image_size from (608,608) to (416,416)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while running code on Linux platform.
I changed the swap memory size which was set to 0 previously to 1 GB and issue got fixed.

For further details you can consult to this link.

https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue but reducing the `batch` size for me did not solve it (My code actually ran fine when the batch value was 16).
I started working on a model under it that involved  scanning pictures that's when I had issues about memory. In the model, there is a `Dense` value, from the Keras package that i had initially set to 4096. I divided this value by 2 and the whole code stop showing the memory error.
Moreover, reducing the value of image resolution would fix the problem too but my pictures were already in low resolution (100X100)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and i tried setting os.environment flag...but it didn't work out.

Then i went ahead and reduced my batch size from 16 to 8, and it started to work fine after then.
As it is because, the train method takes into account the batch size...i feel, reducing the image size would also work..as mentioned above as well.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers suggest to decrease the batch size. If you really want to get the best performance for you model you might need to move to a bigger (cloud) machine for training with higher main memory resources as batch size is a hyper parameter (see kubeflow katib output below for an experiment I've just done)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everyone points at RAM usage. But in my case, it turned out to be a CPU problem, even though the Python complained with the 10% memory usage warning. Try the following:

```
sudo apt install htop

htop
```

This gives you a nice overview of hardware utilization. Then try running your code again  and see exactly which of your resources are the limiting factor.

Good Luck!