# Memory problem when adding dense layer to CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am implementing my first CNN in Tensorflow and I am having trouble when adding the dense layer to my CNN model. Here is the code:

```
batch_size = 4
sample_shape = (batch_size, 24, 30, 30, 5)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv3D(96, kernel_size=(4, 4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=sample_shape))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(1, 1, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))

model.summary()
```

I am getting the following output. Later, my program crashes. What needs so much memory? It seems to be the Dense Layer, but I can't explain it.

```
2021-10-20 19:03:53.219849: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 5662310400 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Comment: Your convolution layers probably need so much memory. Take a look at the number of their parameters.

Comment: The message you showed does look like a warning, not like an error. Are you sure that this is the reason why your program crashes?

Comment: Try `model.summary()` to see the number of parameters your model have, just by looking you have large number of 3D filters, check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304156/tensorflow-allocation-memory-allocation-of-38535168-exceeds-10-of-system-memor).

Comment: What exactly is the crash message?

Answer (score 0):

Your flattened weight shape at the last layer is roughly

```
4 * (24 * 30 * 30 * 64 * 256) = 1,415,577,600
```

That's an insane amount of parameters. Use `MaxPooling3D` between convolutional layers or `GlobalAveragePooling3D` instead of `Flatten` to reduce the number of parameters.