# Disable tensorflow logs when used in extrenal libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are some libraries I use that use tensorflow. Is there an easy way to disable the logging globally or at least find out which class is generating the logs without how to sift through every class and do trial and error

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information

Comment: Thanks but i've already tried that