# Disable Tensorflow JS debugging information

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

How do you disable all debugging logs from Tensorflow JS? In Python you can simply set an environment variable and call a function to also set logging.

[Disable Debugging in Tensorflow (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)

*From the top answer:*

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}

import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('INFO')
```

But how can we do the same for Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you can just set the variable to that run with:

```
$ TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 npm start
```

or you can set it globally in `~/.profile` to disable for every run.

Answer (score 1):

For those attempting to silence model training logs:

```
this.model.fit(tf.tensor(data), tf.tensor(train), {
                shuffle: true,
                ...
                verbose: false <---- turn of verbose reporting  
            })
```