# VS Code and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I just imported the tensorflow module, can anyone tell me why this message keeps coming up on my console every time I run my program and how I can get rid of it?

[image]

EDIT: I found that using

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

before

```
import tensorflow
```

helped clear my console.

Comment: Hi, the errors are related to cuda, its libraries  and the execution environment. Could you try this after importing tensorflow: import os
os.system('cls')

Comment: @smile Hi, I tried that, and those messages still keep coming up.

Comment: could you follow the discussion here [Create a way to control log message output](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258)  and this [debugging info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)  , Thanks

Comment: @smile thank you very much! I found that using import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' before importing tensorflow sorted out the problem!

Comment: It is a pleasure. You can post the answer you discovered so that others can benefit from it. Best