# Error while loading tensorflow model - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I trained and saved my model as .h5 file,and when I am trying to load the model again through the load_model() I am getting this error,here's my entire code and error I got.

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0

```
from tensorflow import keras

age_model_path = r"C:\Users\dipesh\Desktop\Age-Gender Detection\models\Age_Prediction_model.h5"
gender_model_path = r"C:\Users\dipesh\Desktop\Age-Gender Detection\models\Gender_Prediction_model.h5"

age_model = keras.models.load_model(age_model_path)
gender_model = keras.models.load_model(gender_model_path)
```

Error I am getting :

```
23:06:34.517588: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/dipesh/PycharmProjects/Age_Gender_Detection/API.py", line 100, in <module>
    prediction = get_gender_age(img_path,gender_model_path,age_model_path)   File "C:/Users/dipesh/PycharmProjects/Age_Gender_Detection/API.py", line 76, in get_gender_age
    gender_model = keras.models.load_model(gender_model_path)   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 182, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 193, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model.compile(**saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 217, in compile_args_from_training_config
    loss = _deserialize_nested_config(losses.deserialize, loss_config)   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 258, in _deserialize_nested_config
    return deserialize_fn(config)   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py", line 1850, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 360, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)   File "C:\Users\dipesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py", line 163, in from_config
    return cls(**config) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: This similar issue answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298241/what-does-this-tensorflow-message-mean-any-side-effect-was-the-installation-su/) may help you to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Mine did that too, but I realized I could upload my model on Google Colab just fine. So I deduced the problem was about the `load_model` function of `keras.models`, which was then out of date. Updating your TensorFlow will also update Keras, hence enable you to load your model properly.