# While using keras load_model to use my h5 model tensorflow is giving error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metal

This is the error I got while loading my model.
The code I used was simply: model = load_model("modelname.h5")

2022-03-05 17:36:05.008440: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

OS: macOS 12.2.1
Machine: Macbook Pro(2021) M1 Pro chip

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not an error message.

Comment: When I try to load my custom model on jupyter notebook it is giving the message I mentioned above. Should I do something about it or will it be fine even if I don't do anything and continue testing my model?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. If you see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65333085/11505850

> An important part of Tensorflow is that it is supposed to be fast. With a suitable installation, it works with CPUs, GPUs, or TPUs. Part of going fast means that it uses different code depending on your hardware. Some CPUs support operations that other CPUs do not, such as vectorized addition (adding multiple variables at once).

> Tensorflow is simply telling you that the version you have installed can use the AVX [Advanced Vector Extensions] and AVX2 operations and is set to do so by default in certain situations (say inside a forward or back-prop matrix multiply), which can speed things up. This is not an error, it is just telling you that it can and will take advantage of your CPU to get that extra speed out.

If you wish to suppress the message (and all debugging options along with it), you can see this SO which recommends `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'`  as referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121886/11505850