# Tensorflow for a specific cpu instruction set

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

When I run `classifier = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()` on my machine I get the following messages:

```
2022-04-16 20:34:33.552104: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.583160: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.583834: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.584363: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-04-16 20:34:33.584756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.585071: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.585411: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.963910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.964159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.964360: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-04-16 20:34:33.964555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3396 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0
```

I don't understand what half of it means. I searched about  `This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags` part online and what I sort of figured is that my hardware is able to AVX2 FMA operations which is supposed to make tensorflow faster but to do that it needs to be compiled "with appropirate compiler flags".

My question is how do I do just that because I want the most out of my hardware.
Here are my specs:

```
CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz
Dedicated GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
Integrated GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
```

Runtime Environment:

```
Python 3.10.4
tensorflow==2.8.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.24.0
```

Comment: I think Tensor Flow is telling you you've already got what you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298241/what-does-this-tensorflow-message-mean-any-side-effect-was-the-installation-su

Comment: Hey thanks! I guess I'll mark this thread as solved. But I don't exactly know how to do that as I am new to the stack overflow platform.