# How to hide terminal messages while running a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I am running a tensorflow model in python on my local machine which doesn't have any GPU .

While doing so I get a lot of these messages in my terminal ,

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to hide all this messages ?
as my program also takes a lot of time like 20-30 secs to execute after all these messages are appeared on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable I(information) and W(warning). See following QA.
[Disable Tensorflow debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)

I occasionally debug tf code on my laptop PC w/o GPU. Initialization of tf takes time like 20-30sec or more too. After loading bunch of modules, it will take 5-10 times longer than a PC w/ GPU at every epoch. It is the tf's nature.