# How to stop the PNG warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile printing to console?

Tags: tensorflow, libpng

I am trying to run some code which cannot be altered in functionality, but it would be great if I can somehow ignore the warnings or prevent them from being printed to the console, as it congests it and makes it unreadable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tf.autograph.set_verbosity` it's used to control how much info tensorflow logs as indicated in their [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity) for TF2.6

```py
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(
    level=0, alsologtostdout=False
)
```

Check also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information) which covers solutions for multiple versions of tensorflow and python.