# How to stop tensorflow from printing a billion warning regarting cudart64?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have made a simple image classifier in teachable machine, which, as output, prints the label to an image. Example "Apple". This works perfectly fine, but everytime I run the code it displays a TON of warning messages regarding cudart64. I really dont want to install cudart right now, so is there any way i can stop tensorflow to stop printing warning messages?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Tensorflow debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information)

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson No :(
Appending this snippet-
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

isnt working

Comment: Did you do it before or after your `import tensorflow` line?

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson Im not really directly importing tensorflow. Here's the code-
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

but for this, i explicitly imported tensorflow af tf, and added the line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the Tensorflow warnings using below code snippet

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```