# How to disable all tensorflow warnings?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a for loop with several different deep learning models in it that generates this warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001B0A8CC90D0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001B0A6C01940> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

I have tried many different things in the for loop to stop it from popping up with no success. Is there simply a way to disable all warnings?

Comment: This link should help with your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information#:~:text=So%20to%20knock%20out%20these,resetwarnings()%20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to avoid warnings:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

Comment: In detail:- 0 = all messages are logged (default behavior) , 1 = INFO messages are not printed , 2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed , 3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed

Comment: This one doesn't work with "Unable to restore custom metric" warning whereas s510's solution does.

Answer (score 4):

Just set tensorflow logger to ERROR:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```