# Disable Tensorflow logs using tensorflow C api

Tags: c, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow model in C, and I need to have a clean console with only one output for other proramms. But now, when I run the model it prints stuff like this :

```
Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll, Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
```

Is there a way to remove the debugging information? For example in python it can be solved by using information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information) thread:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf
```

But I cant seem to find any other resources for C except this:

```
putenv("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3");
```

But that for some reason doesn't work. (So my idea is to change the default value for this variable (**TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL**) globally in the TF source code or wherever it is, so it's set to 3 every time I use Tensorflow, but I'm not quite sure how to do that)

Answer (score 0):

you can disable tensorflow logs using c api you by setting a new environment variable called TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL.

```
char* new_env = "TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3";
```

By creating this environment variable the tensorflow logs will be disable. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you include

```
    char env[] = "TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3";
    putenv(env);
```

in the beginning of main(), it should work (in both C and C++). It prevents all log messages of the tensorflow that it prints to stderr (3 is maximal severity level).