# How to redirect tensorflow import errors from `stderr` to `stdout`

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, stderr

#### Question

When you import tensorflow, it prints to `stderr` - [bug report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62770#issue-2073291734).

Currently this is confusing my monitoring system and logging these informative messages as errors.

I would like to redirect these messages from `stderr` to `stdout`.

In theory, this should work:

```py
def redirect_tensorflow_logs():
    print("Before - Outside redirect block", file=sys.stderr)
    with redirect_stderr(sys.stdout):
        print("Before -  Inside redirect block", file=sys.stderr)
        import tensorflow as tf
        print("After - Inside redirect block", file=sys.stderr)
    print("After - Outside redirect block", file=sys.stderr)
```

Unfortunately, it is not.  This is the output I am getting:

Output - stderr:

```
Before - Outside redirect block
2024-01-10 14:34:44.164579: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
After - Outside redirect block
```

Output - stdout:

```
Before -  Inside redirect block
After - Inside redirect block
```

Is there a way to redirect these messages from `stderr` to `stdout`?

#### Alternate solutions

I know that set `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121886/251589) to remove these messages entirely.  I would prefer to not do this because at some point, I will want to address these and hiding them will make this harder for future devs to understand what is going on.

I could also redirect ALL output from my program from stderr to stdout via something like this: `python -m myprogram 2>&1`.  This would stop my monitoring system from raising errors but may cause me to miss some items in the future that are **real errors**.